# GCC error for 2D array with fixed row but variable columns

Tags: arrays, c, gcc

The Question asks the User to input a 2D array whose no. of rows are fixed (take rows = 3) and no. of columns are given by the User as follows:

```c
Input:
2 1 2
4 10 20 30 40
5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Here in the first line `2 1 2`, first input tells about the no. of columns in the row index [0] and rest of input are values for row index [0]. And so on for the rest of the lines.
Then, the User enters the row and column index and prints the respective value.
`Input: 1 2`
`Output: 30`

I solved it using the array of pointers as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  
    int a, c;
    int x , y;   // index coordinates
    
    int *pa[3];
    pa[0] = &a;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(i != 0) 
            pa[i] = pa[i-1] + c;   //point to mem address c*sizeof(int) bytes away from prev pointer
        
        scanf("%d", &c);  //input no. of column for row[i]

        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            int k;
            scanf("%d", &k);
            *(pa[i] + j) = k;
        }
    }
    
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("--> %d", *(pa[x] + y));
    
    return 0;
```

This runs correctly on MSVC and Clang but for some reason not on GCC. There is some kind of run-time error during Input in GCC.

PS: I have solved this using dynamic mem allocation but just wanted to know why the above code does not work in case of GCC:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int **data = (int **) malloc(3*sizeof(int*));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int c;
        scanf("%d", &c);
        data[i] = (int *) malloc(c*sizeof(int));
        for(int j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        {
            int k;
            scanf("%d", &k);
            data[i][j] = k;
        }           
    }
    int i, j;
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
    printf("--> %d", data[i][j]);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        free(data[i]);
    
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is only one `int` at `a`, so `pa[0] = &a;` sets `pa[0]` to point to only one `int`. Whatever memory might happen to be around `a`, it has not been reserved for your use with `a` or `pa`. Then `pa[i] = pa[i-1] + c;` just attempts to set `pa[i]` to point to other places in memory, which also have not been reserved for your use. You cannot just set pointers to whatever addresses you like and use the memory there.

Comment: This is why it seems to work on some compilers: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277486)

Comment: @EricPostpischil so basically setting a new pointer to point at memory location based on another pointer would be UB? It has to be of the form `type* p_var = &var` for memory to be reserved properly. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Grey: It is fine to set a pointer based on another pointer, such as `x = y + 3;`, where `x` and `y` are pointers. The issue is, what is this actually pointing at? If there are ten objects at `y`, then you can point at `y+3`, because one of them is there. If there is only one object at `y`, then you are not supposed to point at `y+3`, because there is nothing there that has been reserved for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

the reason the above code doesn't work in gcc is because when you declare `int *pa[3];`
you declare an array of 3 pointers to ints.
because none of the pointers is dynamically allocated when you try to write to `*(pa[i] + j) = k;`

but you didn't allocate memory in that index, which is a dereference of the array of pointers (which gives you the pointer in the i position) and then move `k * sizeof(int)` bytes from that position and dereference that pointer which doesn't belong to you.